# Check ionic installed or not

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

[image]

Now I'm just started ionic and done installation steps. But shows some warning in cmd. How can I check the ionic is installed or not?

Comment: As per your current screenshot, you gotta update your cordova cli version. Exceute 'npm install -g cordova' command from your command prompt

Answer (score 12):

To check ionic installation, run the following from your project folder:

`ionic info`

You should be able to get the output similar to  the one mentioned below:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v6.9.2
```

you can also try using `ionic lib`

Comment: i dont know..how to run.

Comment: @user6721756 you need to execute this "ionic info" command in the command prompt with the path directory being the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Simply type `ionic -v` in your command prompt it will show the version of ionic installed in the system

Comment: ionic -v returns the ionic cli version not ionic library version

Comment: it is not ionic cli version it is ionic version only